# Liferay user authentication

Tags: authentication, liferay, liferay-6

How to authenticate with liferay by passing the parameters as user email and password. If authentication is success then I will redirect to different web web application.Actually i want to authenticate user without using sign in portlet.Is there any way we can hit a url and it gives a response text so we can identify that user is authenticated. i followed this [link](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/05/consuming-liferay-json-web-services.html) but i didn't get proper response.

Comment: For Login you can use AutoLogin Filter.

Comment: Can you please send any sample code to authenticate.

Comment: Its Auto Login Hook not 'filter'. Refer this http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/03/liferay-parameter-auto-login.html

Answer (score 1):

Liferay integrates with a lot of different SSO (Single-Sign-On) systems on the market. Instead of reinventing the wheel, you should use one of those integrations. This way you're free to use whatever your SSO uses to authenticate the user and it will provide your user's identity to Liferay as well as to any other application.

For Liferay EE, you also have the option to make Liferay your "SSO" by utilizing the SAML plugin and creating Liferay into an IdP (Identity Provider) and by making your other application an SP (Service Provider).

The whole field of forwarding the identity of users has been solved and one shouldn't mock around with redirecting with any self-invented authentication scheme IMHO.

Comment: Sir Olaf kock I want to hit webdav url but it is asking credentials.
We are using ntlm n it is working fine but for webdav url it is asking credentials. Do we have any way to avoid credentials prompt for webdav url please.